# ASP.NET Web Deploy times out after x seconds, can only deploy x files at a time

Tags: asp.net, deployment, amazon-ec2, msdeploy, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm unable to reliably use ASP.NET web deployment to push updates to my server running on an EC2 instance.

The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 (fully updated and patched), and it's running the latest version of the Web Deployment Service (3.5, actual version 9.0.176.0). I'm trying under both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015, and try connecting directly to the EC2 instance or via the ELB. In all cases, if the deploy takes more than x seconds, it just hangs and then errors out (many) minutes later.

If the deploy consists of many small files, each subsequent attempt to deploy will upload another handful of files before hanging, like this:

```
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to http://52.8.131.99/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE ...
2>Adding ACL's for path (NeoSmart)
2>Adding ACL's for path (NeoSmart)
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\RestSharp.dll).
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\secure\secrets.release.bin).
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\secure\secrets.sandbox.bin).
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 2 of 10.
```

After abort, restart of VS, and retry, it continues where it left off only to hang again:

```
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to http://52.8.131.99/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE ...
2>Adding ACL's for path (NeoSmart)
2>Adding ACL's for path (NeoSmart)
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll).
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll).
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\System.Web.Http.Common.dll).
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\System.Web.Http.dll).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.
```

If the file it hangs on is too big to go through (for example, the latest version of the AWS SDK, weighing in at 6.3MiB), subsequent restarts won't help any - it hangs on the same file repeatedly:

```
2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to http://52.8.131.99/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE ...
2>Adding ACL's for path (NeoSmart)
2>Adding ACL's for path (NeoSmart)
2>Updating file (NeoSmart\bin\System.Web.Http.dll).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5): Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.  
2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.
```

Deploying to a new EC2 instance takes care of the problem; only a day later I have the same issue and I need to deploy a new Server 2012 instance and deploy all over again. No way, no how.

To me, it looks like the connection is being dropped without acknowledgement somewhere along the line. I'm not sure how/why since I've tried deploying directly to the EC2 instance's public IP and to the ELB. I've tried with w3svc stopped and started, in case it was contention over the target files that was causing the issue, but to no avail. It's *probably* not on my end because creating a new EC2 instance and deploying from the same machine I'm on works without a problem.

Any idea how I can find out what's causing this? Nothing shows up in the event viewer. Is there a better alternative to the Web Deployment Service for pushing updates to ASP.NET websites on IIS?

Any insight would be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a proxy to the environment? It happens to me several time by proxy/VPN restrictions

Comment: No, it's exposed directly to the internet.

Comment: Mmm, rare. Just ideas.... what about deploy with TFS? Or using Publish methods with a shared folder and xml-transformations? But I think the truncate communication will still happens.